# Ember Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, ember.js, emberfire

I've successfully connected my app to Firebase and am authorizing users while also adding additional user information to a `user-profile` model. There's a few things I'd like to do with this data.

First of all, upon signup (username, password), I'm asking the user for some additional information (name, avatar, city, etc). How can I use this data alongside the authed user (i.e. Welcome :name site wide)? Additionally, I'd like this user to only see their own profile and be able to edit their own profile. A bit stumped currently and just looking for next steps...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to handle this.

- For a couple/long lived app, I would use Ember Simple Auth. By complex, I mean needing lots of automatic behavior based on authentication status
- Look into Ember Data adapters and addons like [emberfire](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire), which was designed to be used with firebase. See [Ember Observer](https://emberobserver.com) to find more addons.
- set this information by hand on a Service (and keep your Auth functions there)
- create a user Model, create a user record on login, and reference it anywhere in the app with `peekRecord`. This is helpful if the user has any relational data
- A combination of the two above